# amazon s3 get object info from upload response

Tags: php, api, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I'm uploading images to amazon s3 using PHP. When I upload a file I want to store information about it in my database so I'll make less API requests when I need to get info about the file (file name, size, type)

Creating new objects:

```
    //initiate the class
    $s3 = new AmazonS3();

    $bucket = 'my_bucket';

    //upload the file           
    $response = $s3->create_object($bucket, $filename, array(
                    'fileUpload' => $filepath,
                    'acl' => AmazonS3::ACL_PUBLIC,
                    'contentType' => $file_type,
                    'storage'     => AmazonS3::STORAGE_REDUCED,
                    'headers'     => array( // raw headers
                          'Cache-Control' => 'max-age=315360000', 
                          'Expires' => gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s T", strtotime("+5 years"))
                    )

    ));                 

    var_dump($response->isOK());
```

After a successful upload, is it possible to get the file name, size, and file type from the `$response` variable without making new GET requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those values aren't in `$response`, but you don't need them. You know everything you want to know already:

- The file name is `$filename`.
- The file size can be determined by `filesize($filepath)`.
- The file type is `$file_type`.

Comment: Yes I have the values beforehand but maybe S3 changes something on upload (not sure if that ever happens...) The `$response` is actually an array with a lot of values returned from the api.

Comment: None of the values you've mentioned will ever be changed on upload.

Answer (score 0):

I can access the returned array from `$response` using `header`

For example to get the file size

```
$response->header['_info']['size_upload']
```